# Can I add a newline to the Clojure REPL prompt?

Tags: clojure

I am a Python guy new to Clojure.

I like a bit of "air" around my REPL prompt. By air I mean a blank line between prompts.

In a Python REPL I can `import sys` and write `sys.ps1='\n>>> '`

Alternatively I could modify `sys.ps1` in the `code.interact` source.

I found the following code in `c:\clojure\src\clj\clojure\main.clj`

```
(defn repl-prompt  
  "Default :prompt hook for repl"  
  []  
  (printf "%s=> " (ns-name *ns*)))
```

I added a newline at `"\n%s=>"` and fired up the REPL.

Wait ...that didn't work. `<sad face>`

My question is, why didn't it work?

I am using the basic Clojure 1.4.0 REPL on Windows XP (JVM=1.6.0).

Comment: It should work. I guess the changes you made are not reflected in REPL. What did you do after you made the change to main.clj?

Comment: @Ankur. I tried invoking `closure.main/repl-prompt` but nothing seemed to work. Thanks to BLUEPIXY for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**E.g.**

```
user=> (defn prompt [] (printf "my\n%s=>" (ns-name *ns*)))
#'user/prompt
user=> (clojure.main/repl :prompt prompt)
my
user=>
```

Comment: when replace source, compile jar. in repl namespace clojure.main redefine repl-prompt and execute `(clojure.main/repl)`, system use new  repl-prompt